# wamp php CLI has stopped working

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I installed `wamp server 2.2` with `php 5.3.10` and `apache 2.2.21`. But when I want to execute some `symfony` command the response from my Windows 7 Home Premium is:

```
php -> CLI has stopped working
```

Comment: do you have tried with setting php.exe in environment variables, and executing commmand like > php symfony .... ?

Comment: This thread may helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671995/php-cli-has-stopped-working Try the answers given here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP -> CLI has stopped working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671995/php-cli-has-stopped-working)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error for a long time. It turned out I was on a slightly older version of Xdebug (php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll).

I replaced that file with "php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll" and it magically started working immediately.

I'm on wamp, and I updated both php.ini files (one is for cli, one for normal use) with the latest filename.
"zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll"

Then dropped the new file into the php ext folder and instant success. Hope this helps.