# CLI has stopped working on wamp server using Laravel Artisan Command

Tags: php, laravel, windows-8, wamp, command-line-interface

I am trying to update inventory for each 'vendors' in my db using a terminal artisan command.

The code executes perfectly in browser, but in the terminal I get a "CLI has stopped working" error on my second iteration on the this line:

```
$updateList = DB::table('inventory_variants')->where("vendor_id", "=", $v->id)->whereIn('id', $inventory["ids"])->get();
```

Overall code:

```
foreach ($vendors as $v) {
    $this->line($v->name.": Request Report");
    $v->store = Vendor::newInstance($v->store_id, $v->api_secret_key);
    $v->store->setInventory(); //Makes Curl Api call and sets inventory
}

foreach ($vendors as $v) {
    if ($v->store->issetInventory()) {
        $this->line($v->name.": Report Found, Starting Update");
        $inventory = $v->store->getInventory();

        $toUpdateItems = array('quantity' => array(), 'price' => array());

        $updateList = DB::table('inventory_variants')->where("vendor_id", "=", $v->id)->whereIn('id', $inventory["id"])->get();

        $this->updateInventory($toUpdateItems,$inventory); // Sets & Updates matching inventory     
    }           
}
```

I am working on windows 8, using wamp 2.5 server, with php 5.5.12, and the laravel framework.

I have read the previous posts:
[PHP -> CLI has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671995/php-cli-has-stopped-working)
[PHP inbuilt server gives "CLI has stopped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753910/php-inbuilt-server-gives-cli-has-stopped-working)
[wamp php CLI has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664370/wamp-php-cli-has-stopped-working)

I have tried re installing wamp with the latest version. I have tried updating to the latest php, but can't figure out what to do.