# CLI stopped working when WAMP Server was started

Tags: php, wamp

I have an error message that CLI has stopped working when I start wamp server. Anyone please help!

Please see snapshot bellow

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP -> CLI has stopped working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671995/php-cli-has-stopped-working)